# UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException spring controller don't mapping request, error 400

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have write in my Spring @controller this mapping of request, it accepts request and parameter "tipoLista,numPagina"

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/evento/approvatutti", params = "{tipoLista,numPagina}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView approvaTuttiGliEventi(@RequestParam("tipoLista") String tipoLista, @RequestParam("numPagina") String numPagina, ModelAndView model) {
        ....bla bla ...bla...
    }
```

When i call `localhost:8084/context/admin/evento/approvatutti?tipoLista=valueOfParameter&numPagina=0`

I received error code 400, bad request. I have enabled TRACE level logging and I receive this message:

```
Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "{tipoLista,numPagina}" not met for actual request parameters: tipoLista={approvabili}, numPagina={0}

DEBUG - nseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "{tipoLista,numPagina}" not met for actual request parameters: tipoLista={approvabili}, numPagina={0}

DEBUG - ltHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "{tipoLista,numPagina}" not met for actual request parameters: tipoLista={approvabili}, numPagina={0}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `params` attribute of `@RequestMapping` expects a `String[]` with](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)

> Same format for any environment: a sequence of "myParam=myValue" style
>   expressions

So each `String` in the array is of the format

```
paramName=paramValue
```

but you can omit the `=paramValue`. But you are providing a single `String` value like

```
{tipoLista,numPagina}
```

this would mean the request query string would have to look like

```
?{tipoLista,numPagina}=someValue
```

which obviously makes no sense and Spring complains

```
Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "{tipoLista,numPagina}" not met for actual request parameters: tipoLista={approvabili}, numPagina={0}
```

Instead, you can change it to

```
params = {"tipoLista","numPagina"}
```

but this is not necessary. Get rid of the `params` attribute all together. You already have `@RequestParam` parameters in your method which are required.

Comment: Thank you very much, there is the solution :-) Thank you Sotirios!